# Beautiful soup div with class and id both

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am beginner and want to ask how to extract data from following type of code using beautiful soup:

```
<div class="about-book" id="aboutbook">
Blah blah blah
</div>
```

How to get "Blah blah blah" when there is "about-book" with different ids and "aboutbook" with different class names.What I want is combination of the class name and id.

Answer (score 5):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="about-book" id="aboutbook">
Blah blah blah
</div>""")

print([x.text for x in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"about-book","id":"aboutbook"})])
[u'\nBlah blah blah\n']
```

If there is only one:

```
  print(soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"about-book","id":"aboutbook"}).text)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bigpm.py", line 31, in <module>
    print([ x.text for x in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"about-book"}) if x["id"] == "aboutbook"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: should have been .get

Comment: you could also do `attrs={'id': 'aboutbook', 'class': 'about-book'}` and save yourself an `if` statement...

Answer (score 1):

Try `"div#aboutbook.about-book"`

Using beautifulsoup, you can write it like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) soup.find_all("div", class_="about-book", id="aboutbook")
```

Comment: can you give example how to write the same in beautifulsoup bcz it does not seem to work

Comment: Going based off the docs:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find_all("div", class_="about-book", id="aboutbook")`